# Crear y destruir hilos con Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy haciendo pruebas con C++ y Qt. Quiero hacer un programa que según los datos que encuentre en la base de datos cree X hilos para realizar cada uno de ellos un proceso laaaaargo. Este proceso se debe repetir indefinidamente mientras el usuario no lo detenga.

Para ello tiene dos opciones: 
* Detener el proceso temporalmente. Típico "start/stop".
* Reiniciarlos.

Reiniciarlos tiene sentido cuando el usuarios ha modificado los datos almacenados en la base de datos o archivos (la configuración).

Si lo reinicia quiero eliminar *todo*. Eliminar los hilos creados de forma dinámica y los objetos que se han movido a estos hilos para realizar el trabajo. Después habría que volver a empezar el proceso desde cero.

Se que se podría decir al usuarios que cerrara la aplicación y volviera ha ejecutarla, pero no sería elegante. Me gustaría aprender a hacerlo bien.

Este es el código que empleo para las pruebas:

myWorker.h

```
#ifndef MYWORKER_H
#define MYWORKER_H

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

namespace jlu
{
    class myWorker : public QObject
    {
            Q_OBJECT

        public:
            explicit myWorker ();
            ~myWorker ();
            void setWorkerID (int workID);
        signals:
            void startProcess();
        public slots:
            void changeStatus (int id, bool newStatus);
            void process();

        private:
            void loadConfigData();

            // Propiedades de la clase:
            bool isActive;
           int myID;
    };
}


#endif // MYWORKER_H
```

myWorker.cpp

```
#include "myworker.h"

jlu::myWorker::myWorker()
{
    connect (this, SIGNAL (startProcess()),
             this, SLOT (process()));
}

jlu::myWorker::~myWorker()
{
    // Mensaje que uso para comprobar si se ha eliminado o no.
    qDebug() << "Se ha eliminado al hilo con ID: " << myID;
}

void jlu::myWorker::setWorkerID (int workID)
{
    if (0 <= workID)
    {
        myID = workID;
    }
    else
    {
        myID = 0;
    }
}

void jlu::myWorker::changeStatus (int id, bool newStatus)
{
    if (myID != id)
    {
        return;
    }

    isActive =  newStatus;

    if (isActive)
    {
        emit startProcess();
    }
}

void jlu::myWorker::process()
{
    loadConfigData(); // Carga toda la información necesaria para funcionar.
    qDebug() << "Se inicia el proceso con id = " << myID;

    while (isActive)
    {
        // Un laaargo proceso que se repita indefinidamente

        // Atendemos los eventos que se hayan producido.
        QCoreApplication::processEvents (QEventLoop::AllEvents);
    }

    qDebug() << "Proceso detenido.";
}

void jlu::myWorker::loadConfigData()
{
    // Carga datos desde la base de datos.
    // Carga datos de archivos de configuración etc.
}
```

manageWorkers.h

```
#ifndef MANAGEWORKERS_H
#define MANAGEWORKERS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include "myworker.h"

namespace jlu
{
    class manageWorkers : public QObject
    {
            Q_OBJECT
        public:
            explicit manageWorkers (QObject * parent = nullptr);
            ~manageWorkers();
            void loadAndStartAllWorkers();
        signals:
            void changeStatusOfWorker (int id, bool newStatus);
        public slots:
            void killallWorkers();
        private:
            int numWorkers;
            QThread * myThreads = NULL;
            myWorker * myProcess = NULL;
    };
}
#endif // MANAGEWORKERS_H
```

manageWorkers.cpp

```
#include "manageworkers.h"

jlu::manageWorkers::manageWorkers (QObject * parent) : QObject (parent)
{

}

jlu::manageWorkers::~manageWorkers() {}


void jlu::manageWorkers::loadAndStartAllWorkers()
{
    numWorkers = 4; // Esto es realmente el resultado de una consulta SQL

    if (0 == numWorkers)
    {
        return;
    }

    myThreads = new QThread[numWorkers];
    myProcess = new jlu::myWorker[numWorkers];

    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
    {
        myProcess[i].setWorkerID (i); // Se tomará de la consulta realizada
        myProcess[i].moveToThread (&myThreads[i]);

        connect (&myThreads[i], SIGNAL (finished()),
                 &myProcess[i], SLOT (deleteLater()));
        connect (this, SIGNAL (changeStatusOfWorker (int, bool)),
                 &myProcess[i], SLOT (changeStatus (int, bool)));
        // Demás conexiones necesarias

        myThreads[i].start();
        // Iniciamos el proceso.
        emit changeStatusOfWorker (i, true);
    }
}

void jlu::manageWorkers::killallWorkers()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
    {
        qDebug() << "Se detiene el hilo n. " << i;
        emit changeStatusOfWorker (i, false);
        myThreads[i].wait (1000);
        myThreads[i].quit();
    }

    qDebug() << "Se han detenido todos los hilos";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDateTime>


#include "manageworkers.h"

#define DATETIME_FORMAT "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"




// Programa principal solo para testear el reinicio de los objetos.
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a (argc, argv);

    jlu::manageWorkers * myControl = new jlu::manageWorkers();
    myControl->loadAndStartAllWorkers();
    qDebug () << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString (DATETIME_FORMAT);

    QTimer::singleShot (10000, myControl, SLOT (killallWorkers()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

En este código lo que hago es en manageWorkers crear tantos hilos y objetos "Workers" como hagan falta y los inicializo. Después tras 10 segundos de funcionamiento, solo para las pruebas y test, elimino (al menos es lo que estoy intentando) los hilos y los objetos "Workers" asociados.

En teoría al finalizar un QThread se debería finalizar el objeto "Worker":

```
connect (&myThreads[i], SIGNAL (finished()), &myProcess[i], SLOT (deleteLater()));
```

Pero esto no funciona. El programa se rompe.

He probado a cambiar el orden de las instrucciones:

```
 myThreads[i].wait (1000);
 myThreads[i].quit();
```

Si hago solo:

```
emit changeStatusOfWorker (i, false);
myThreads[i].wait();
```

El proceso se detiene, pero no se elimina.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto y **eliminar** correctamente los objetos "Workers" y los threads creados dinámicamente?

Comment: Prueba a lanzar ventanas de advertencia cuando reciba cualquier señal el `worker`, y ver si al cerrar la ventana, matas o no al `worker`.

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos uso un qDebug en el destructor y en el depurador también he comprobado que no se destruyen. De echo el programa se **rompe**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Ya lo tengo resuelto!

La solución está en eliminar la conexión:

```
connect (&myThreads[i], SIGNAL (finished()),
             &myProcess[i], SLOT (deleteLater()));
```

Y eliminar los objetos `myProcess` manualmente en el método `killallWorkers`, el cual quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
void jlu::manageWorkers::killallWorkers()
{
    qDebug() << " keys: " << netsConfigList.keys();

    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
    {
        qDebug() << "Se detiene el hilo n. " << i;
        emit changeStatusOfWorker (i, false);
        myThreads[i].quit();         // <---  El orden importa!! 
        myThreads[i].wait (1000);
    }

    // Ahora sí se eliminan los objetos y se libera la memoria correctamente.
    delete []myThreads;
    delete []myProcess;

    qDebug() << " Se han eliminado todos los hilos";
}
```

El problema estaba en que tras hacer el `myThreads[i].quit()` se lanzaba la señal que le decía al objeto `myProcess[i]` que se destruyera cuando pudiera... Esto parece que dejaba al objeto que estaba en el otro hilo medio colgado por ahí y daba el fallo que comentaba.

Así que ahora ya puedo reiniciar los hilos y sus procesos tantas veces como quiera y liberando la memoria como toca.